# Are questions about the sociology of space travel on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm asking this question after a user posted [this question on SFF SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270824/how-to-travel-through-space-peacefully) which was closed as being off-topic (it definitely was). A later comment suggested Space Exploration but I could tell the question wasn't focused enough.
(Nevertheless, the user re-posted it on SESE).

This got me thinking, since social sciences are so poorly represented as SE sites, that the sites that touch on specific aspects of those sciences might sometimes pick up the slack. (For example, Earth Science SE sometimes answers questions that are pure geography).

For example, if the user reframed their question in terms of actual studies done, might it possibly have been on-topic here?

Answer (score 7):

This question could have been made on-topic for SFF.SE by asking whether there have been any sci-fi stories about crew members (including human, alien, and artificially intelligent) going bats**t crazy; there have been several.

This question could also be made on-topic for Space.SE by asking whether NASA, Roscosmos, and China filter their astronaut / cosmonaut / taikonaut candidates for psychological / psychiatric conditions (they do) and what those organizations do to maintain their psychological health once selected. The screening and maintenance obviously are not perfect; witness the (now ex) astronaut who bought adult diapers so as to drive from Houston to the Cape ASAP to confront her lover (also a now ex-astronaut).

The problem with such questions is that this is asking for what is potentially Personally identifiable information (PII). NASA in general does not release information on astronaut medical conditions (including psychological / psychiatric conditions) due to PII concerns. They also do not release much information on the astronaut candidate screening processes because doing so might increase the likelihood of a candidate gaming the selection process.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of double-blind studies, where a large-enough sample of participants would make summary statistics significant. No PII needed there.

Comment: Actually, and unfortunately, "Have there been any sci-fi stories about X?" questions are quickly and soundly closed in in SciFi SE. The "loophole" is to ask for *the first* story about X or some other item that allows for the possibility of a correct answer. There's a powerful and vocal minority that does not like even those questions, but if you stand by them you can usually keep them open. "Are they any?" is a "list question" and so is quickly close-able.

Comment: @uhoh I don't participate in that part of the SE network. I have seen other related parts of the network where questions along the lines of "What was the name of this book I read years ago? I can't remember! Here's what I do remember ..." are accepted and answered.

Comment: @DavidHammen oh for sure; as long as the question has the possibility of a correct answer.